# Onclick Win By Percentage and Show Number

Tags: php, jquery

I created a betting script, and I need help for button High or Low.

I created an input value which is to determind the chance. For example chance to win is 5%. So when user click the button high/low, the function will consider chance to win (5%). That mean the user 95% will get loss.

I implemented a random number when the user click on it.

For example, 
- chance to win is 5%
- button HIGH is random number between 950000 ~ 999999
- button LOW is random number between 0 ~ 49999

how to get the result on button click on high or low, the user will win by chance 5% and will loss by chance 95%

please help
thanks

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've already tried

Comment: It is probably against site culture to outright provide the users with their solution, but I want to help others, and I wish I was helped in turn. I like StackOverflow as the site to go to get your coding questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code that does exactly just that. Here's [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/Dragon-God/ProbabilitySuite).
Here's the section relevant to you:

#### probSelect.php

```
<?php
    require_once("confirm.php");
/*
*   A function to select an element from an array with indicated probabilites.
*   Input: 
*       An associative array whose keys are the elements to be selected from, and whose values are the associated probabilities.
*   Output: 
*       The selected element, or "NULL" if an invalid probability distribution was supplied. 
*   @params 
*       array $arr: The array containing the probability distribution.
*/  
    function probSelect(array $arr) 
    {
        if(confirm($arr))
        {
            $var = lcg_value(); #The random float that would be used to select the element.
            $sum = 0;
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
            {
                $sum += $value;
                if($var <= $sum)
                {
                    return $key;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("ERROR!!! The supplied probability distribution must sum to 1. <br>");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

---

### Explanation

`confirm()` is a function that confirms that a valid probability distribution was supplied to `probSelect()`. The meat of the code is in the `if` block that executes if the supplied probability distribution is valid.
`lcg_value()` generates a random floating point number between `0` and `1`. This random number (`$var`) is the active ingredient for my algorithm.
`foreach` is then used to loop through the array summing the values of the array as it does so. If `$var` is less than or equal to the current sum, we return the current key (which I would call landing on that key).

The above algorithm generates the probabilistic selection because the chances of `$var` landing on any given key is exactly the same as the value of that key (which is its probability mass).

Comment: I posted the code in the above answer. Feel free to check out the repository as well.